# Xcode how to force rebuild dependency framework target

Tags: ios, xcode

in my xcode project, there are 2 target,one Framework, one iOS application,link and import this Framework in the iOS application target.

every time I change the code in Framework target,build this iOS application target will not automatically re build Framework

i want to automatically re build the current dependency framework target when build the iOS Application target,how to do this?(Any setup item?)

Answer (score 5):

Find a solution:

in iOS application target, Add Framework to `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` items.